# On my Google Maps when I zoom out beyond level 10 all my markers disappear

Tags: google-maps, maps

My google maps work fine at a zoom level higher than 10, but if I zoom out my markers disappear. I cant see where the error is. Have tried using v3 and v2. Also changing from .png markers to .gif. Have tried with fewer points on the map.

Its the same problem across all the browsers.

Thanks for helping...

http://test.onionring.co.uk/map-towns.asp?region=Cheshire

Nick

Comment: The code in that link is Google Maps API v2, which is deprecated and may stop working anytime after May 19, 2013, it doesn't make sense to develop new functionality in that version of the API. It would be better if you posted the v3 version (and posted the problematic code, rather than a link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem (the marker manager is doing what you are telling it to do):

```
manager.addMarkers(batch, 11);
```

According to the [documentation](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.1/docs/reference.html), 11 is the minimum zoom (the first zoom at which the marker will appear).

```
addMarker(marker:Marker, minZoom:Number, opt_maxZoom:Number)
```